# Create new data base phalcon php

Tags: phalcon

I need to create a new database in the Phlacon PHP.

Ex.: Create schema **TEST001**;

In my micro application I need to generate new databases. But the default Phalcon database is already set to **COMPANY**

How can I do on Phalcon PHP?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to update your questions with what you have tried to get the objective. If you followed any steps or any tutorial, did search on google or stackoverflow. This is a very generic question and most of the users will not respond if you do not have enough details. FOr aexample a little bit of googling can get you to this page https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/4332/how-to-create-database-with-phalcon. Without you showing the interest in trying to solve problems you face it is highly unlikely to get necessary help in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new connection in services:

$di->setShared('db_teste', function () {
    $config = $this->getConfig();

```
$class = 'Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\\' . $config->database->adapter;
$connection = new $class([
        'host'     => $config->database->host,
        'username' => $config->database->username,
        'password' => $config->database->password,
        'charset'  => $config->database->charset
]);

return $connection;
```

});

And in the method I did so:

$this->getDi()->getShared('db_teste')->query("CREATE DATABASE COMPANY");

Thank you @klay

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use raw query directly in controoler's action.
Please refer to [How to run RAW SQL query in PhalconPHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934071/how-to-run-raw-sql-query-in-phalconphp)

Comment: Thank you for help.

I created a new connection:

$di->setShared('db_teste', function () {
 $config = $this->getConfig();

 $class = 'Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\\' . $config->database->adapter;
 $connection = new $class([
   'host'     => $config->database->host,
   'username' => $config->database->username,
   'password' => $config->database->password,
   'charset'  => $config->database->charset
 ]);

 return $connection;
});

And in the method I did so:

$this->getDi()->getShared('db_teste')->query("CREATE DATABASE COMPANY");